# IE 11 bufferData() does not allocate/transfer data to VBO

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webgl, internet-explorer-11

I'm having an issue with IE 11, bufferData call where the argument is a DataView instance.  In IE 11 This results in INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: Insufficient buffer size error during a call to drawArrays().  The code works in Chrome 61 and Firefox 56.

My question is for experienced WebGL/JS developers, whether this is an IE bug or my misuse of DataView and for any workarounds.  In my application the design I wanted was: to allocate a byte array buffer, manipulate it using an appropriate data view (like Float32Array) depending on context in some part of the program, and then copy it to WebGL VBO buffer in different part of the program without having to figure out a specific DataView instance (like Float32Array).

I replicated the problem using simple triangle WebGL example from soulwire http://jsfiddle.net/soulwire/XLnVW/ as a base.  My modifications are posted below and available http://jsfiddle.net/1h3225uj/4/:

```
function initBuffers() {
    //allocate space for 3 * vec3 * 4 bytes/component
    rawPolygonArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(3 * 3 * 4);

    //fill vertices using Float32Array view
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView = new Float32Array(rawPolygonArrayBuffer);
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[0] = -0.5;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[1] = -0.5;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[2] = 0.0;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[3] = 0.0;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[4] = 0.5;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[5] = 0.0;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[6] = 0.5;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[7] = -0.5;
    float32PolygonArrayBufferView[8] = 0.0;

    //Create a generic view into ArrayBuffer object
    genericPolygonArrayBufferView = new DataView(rawPolygonArrayBuffer);

    vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    //gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, float32PolygonArrayBufferView, gl.STATIC_DRAW); //<-- WORKS
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, genericPolygonArrayBufferView, gl.STATIC_DRAW); //<-- Doesn't work
    glBufferAllocatedBytes = gl.getBufferParameter(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.BUFFER_SIZE);
    console.log("glBufferAllocatedBytes: " + glBufferAllocatedBytes);
    console.log("rawPolygonArrayBuffer.byteLength: " + rawPolygonArrayBuffer.byteLength);
}
```

The console.log shows VBO buffer size to be 0 bytes on IE, and 36 bytes in Firefox/Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WebGL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.5) states `bufferData` and `bufferSubData` to accept `BufferSource`s which is in turn [specified on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BufferSource) as:

> BufferSource is a typedef used to represent objects that are either themselves an **ArrayBuffer**, or which are a **TypedArray** providing an **ArrayBufferView**.

[`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) is none of that, however it does expose its underlying `ArrayBuffer` via its `buffer` member, so you can simply use that to upload the data:

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, genericPolygonArrayBufferView.buffer, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Ok, it seems I incorrectly thought classes like Float32Array can be a view into an ArrayBuffer are therefore a "subclass" of DataView.

Comment: I'd say the right way to think about it is that `DataView` is a utility to work with `ArrayBuffer`s.